# Opening a modal from another modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I'm opening a modal bootstrap from another modal, closing the first one and then showing the new modal, however in the new modal I need to open another small modal or even a datepicker, and those don't show, the background goes darker but whatever i need to show doesn't popup, it seems to be hidden, does anyone know what I can do to solve this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for correcting my text Gherbi Hicham.

Answer (score 1):

If the backgroud goes darker that means your popup is populating you jst go though your small popup that you are opening from another threre might some alignment issues of it

Comment: I was able to get the small modal working, but the datepicker is still not showing up, it doesn't even make the background darker, what could it be ? (i think it's not supposed to get the background darker as it's not another modal it's just a datepicker from jquery and bootstrap together)